# How can I use multi-line input with QuickCheck in doctest?

Tags: haskell, doctest, quickcheck

From [Doctest's readme](https://github.com/sol/doctest), one can use doctest with QuickCheck, like this:

```
-- |
-- prop> sort xs == (sort . sort) (xs :: [Int])
```

I would like to describe this property using multiple lines, probably like

```
-- |
-- prop> sort xs ==
--            (sort . sort) (xs :: [Int])
```

Doctest itself supports multi-line input (again from readme)

```
-- |
-- >>> :{
--  let
--    x = 1
--    y = 2
--  in x + y + multiline
-- :}
-- 6
```

and I tried several similar syntaxes I came up with, such as

```
-- |
-- prop> :{ sort xs ==
--           (sort . sort) (xs :: [Int])
-- }:
```

without any success. (In the example above, the error message is  `parse error on input '{'`.)

How can I use multi-line input with Quickcheck in doctest?

Comment: I believe that just like ghci, the multi-line syntax requires that the open and closing symbols be on their own line. Your example won't work because `:{` is not on its own line.

Comment: @user2407038 I believe you are right about that case. I can't avoid parse error and have `prop>` recognize multiple lines as the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of September 2017, [doctest does not allow multi-line properties](https://github.com/sol/doctest/issues/131). However, you can use `quickCheck` as usual in a doctest:

```
-- >>> import Test.QuickCheck
-- >>> import Data.List (sort)
-- >>> :{
--  quickCheck $ \xs -> 
--      sort xs ==
--            (sort . sort) (xs :: [Int])
-- :}
-- +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

That's verbose, but will enable you to write arbitrary long checks. Note that you can always create a `prop_*` function and use that in your doctest.